# How to prove the cofactor of a matrix is related to it's minor?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I prove $A_{ij}$, the cofactor of $a_{ij}$ of a matrix $D$, has the property $A_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}M_{ij}$, where $M_{ij}$ is the minor obtained by deleting the $i$th row and $j$th column?

Comment: Isn't it the definition?

Comment: Not according to the textbook I'm working off of. They prove it using the $i=1, j=1$ case, and then move the element $a_{11}$ "around" to show the general case. I'm having trouble conceptualizing the $i=1, j=1$ case.

Comment: But what's your textbook definition of a cofactor then?

Comment: It states that the cofactor of $a_{ij}$ is the resultant expression when $a_{ij}$ is factored out of the determinant  $D(X)=\Sigma(-1)^{N(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)}a_{\alpha_{1}1}a_{\alpha_{2}2}...a_{\alpha_{n}n}$, where the matrix $X$ is an $n$ by $n$ square matrix and $N(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)$ is a function that counts the number of transpositions in the sequence.

Comment: I see. That's not the most direct and simple definition. That means you consider the determinant as a polynomial linear in the $n^2$ variables $a_{ij}$, develop it along the $i$-th row (or the $j$-th column) and consider the coefficient of $a_{ij}$. Btw, the function $N$ is called the `signature` of the permutation $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of $i=j=1$, $A_11$ will be the sum of the terms $(1)^{N(\alpha_1=1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n)} a_{\alpha_2 2} \cdots a_{\alpha_n n}$. Observe that there is no transposition (or inversion) that contains $a_{11}$. So $N(\alpha_1=1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n)=N(\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n)$. Then we have the sum of terms like $(-1)^{N(\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n) } a_{\alpha_2 2} \cdots a_{\alpha_n n}$. The sum of these term, however, is the determinant of the following matrix

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2 n} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        a_{n 2} & \cdots & a_{nn} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
and clearly this matrix is the minor $M_{11}$ of the original matrix. Thus $A_{11}=M_{11}$. This shows the claim $A_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j} M_{ij}$ when $i=j=1$. In the general case you just move the element from $i$th row $j$th column to the first row first column, and follow a similar argument.